# CodeIgniter session issue after sign out browser back button landed to the secured page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, browser-cache

I am using `codeIgniter 2.1.4` in my application. If am in a page that require authentication. Then I logout after logout if I use browser back button it will get me back to the secured page. I can only view the page. If I refresh or click on any link it will redirect me to the login page.

I think it's a cache issue? But I am not sure.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418964/codeigniter-back-button-after-logout?rq=1#answer-10439679

Comment: @oikonomopo fun fact: Safari on iPad (probably all iDevices) doesn't obey. Apple seems to be too cool to follow the rules.

Comment: ok, thanks to @MonkeyZeus consider also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297122/preventing-cache-on-back-button-in-safari-5/5305905#5305905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include these headers in the constructor function of the controller to prevent the caching of previous page

If you want the **Code Igniter's way of doing it** include the below code

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

**PHP's way of doing it** use the below lines of code

```
header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 2):

paste  `$this->output->nocache();`  in your `__construct()` function after `parent::__construct();`

Comment: Can you explain why that will help?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the client's browser from caching the site by adding

```
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

into your HTML header.