# Codeigniter session data not destroying until refresh the page

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am trying to develop a registration system.

```
Registration Info -> Subscription -> Success page
```

While submitting the user information, I created a `session_data` and in the Success page `controller`, I unset the session so that the user cannot go back to the subscription page.

The `subscription` and `success` controller is restricted if `session data` is not set.

**Subscription Controller** & **Success Controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();


    if (! $this->session->userdata('st_guid'))
    {
        redirect('register');
    }
}
```

And in **Success Controller Index** I unset the userdata.

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->view('success');

    // Unset session data
    $this->session->unset_userdata('st_guid');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

Problem is, if I click the browser back button it easily load the `subscription` page and click the forward button it loads the `success` page while I already unset the session data. If I refresh the page only then the session data getting destroyed and redirected to `registration` page.

What should I do ?

I am using `Codeigniter 2.2.6`

Comment: try unset the session variable first then load the view. also make sure that you have loaded the session library

Comment: @PunitGajjar Thanks for the comment. I tried it, but the result is same as before.

Comment: You can find the answer here in this question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418964/codeigniter-back-button-after-logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418964/codeigniter-back-button-after-logout)